# Why don't Alacarte and Menulibre work for me when I try to change icons?

Tags: plank

I tried to use both alacarte and menulibre to change my dock icons (for new PNG icons) but the changes don't work (only) on the dock even after I reboot.

I tested with Chrome, the files folder icon and Ephiphany.

I tried to restart plank only in the terminal. It didn't help.